# has been responsible vs was responsible

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Here's the example sentence.

"There have been arguments about who was/has been responsible for the accident."

I'm not a native speaker. In my language(which is Chinese), when you cause an accident, and then you are immediately responsible for the accident. Additionally, responsibility lasts forever, so if I used "was" in the sentence, I feel weird, and "has been" looks like the more proper one. However, I really want to hear the opinion from the native speaker.

Which one is more correct in this sentence? 
What's the difference between them?

Comment: Does the present perfect tense apply now? That is, when did responsibility for the accident happen? Is it still on-going?

Comment: I have already edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: If the person is living, the present tense may be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In your quote, the term *responsible* refers to the *action* leading to the accident.

> **responsible** *adjective*
>   2 Being the primary cause of something and so able to be blamed or credited for it.
>   ‘Gooch was responsible for 198 of his side's 542 runs’
>   [- Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/responsible)

While the consequences continue, and perhaps the moral responsibility as well, the action itself happened at a point in time that has passed.

The *has been* variant isn’t appropriate because it suggests an extended period of responsibility rather than a single episode. It can be used where the construction doesn’t allow the simple past tense, though:

- *He has been responsible for the accident. (This invites the retort “So, when did he relinquish that responsibility?”)
- The judge considered him to have been responsible for the accident. (Note 1: “to was ...” would be ungrammatical. Note 2: [link](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-have-been-responsible-for-vs-to-be-responsible-for.1992808/) to a google result that motivated this example.)

Answer (score -2):

I think it depends upon the context.If we are on the spot of the accident we say *who is responsible for the accident.*?

If we met the person after some time  or we were talking about the accident  later we say *who was responsible for the accident*?

I have searched on the internet for the usage of **responsible**
It is used in the simple present, past and future but not in the perfect tenses when we refer to a single incident such as accident

**Who has been responsible for the accident is not possible since it is a single accident**